# how to turn off viewport resizer when using Control+Shift+J to Open the Console panel on chrome?

Tags: javascript, css

I am using viewport resizer with chrome to see what happen with my code at some devices.

But, my problem is, when I use ctrl + shift + j to see the console on chrome, it open the viewport resizer. As you can see in this picture[image: picture about my problem]

So, I want to use viewport resizer but I just want to see the console on chrome as usual.

Could you please help me to solve this problem ?
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Click the blue icon in the top bar of the dev tools (next to Elements) or press `CTRL`+`Shift`+`M` while the focus is inside the dev tools.

Comment: Hi! If I understand your problem correctly, you want to disable the mobile view so that it doesn't appear as default, when you open the devtools. If so, just click on the blue mobile view icon next to Elements in left.

Comment: @Christopher thank you for your comment, your way are right and now I can solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Click on blue view port icon to remove view port and press Ctrl + Shift + I instead to open Chrome Dev Tools[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmZjU.png)